# Database URL of a postgresql database residing in an Azure VM

Tags: django, database, postgresql, ubuntu, azure

I have an Azure VM that runs Ubuntu and has a Django app of mine along with its postgresql database installed on it.

Moreover, I also have an Azure Web App that was created with Django, which I then connected to github, and pulled the source code for the same app I have on the aforementioned Azure VM.

**I now want the settings.py in this Django Azure Web App to point to the database residing in the Azure VM.**

Normally, the way to do this is to list the database url in the app's settings.py. **My question is:** what would be the database url for my postgresql database installed in the Azure VM, if one was to try and access it from an Azure Web App (i.e. external to the Azure VM)? Would it be: `postgres://AzureVM'sFQDN:5432/nameofdatabase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have opened port 5432 on the VM, that would be the right string to connect to your database from anywhere. Have you tried to connect your development machine to this database?

If you have created your set-up with the new resource manager deployment model of azure, you should also be able to create both the web-app and the database VM within the same virtual network. This way, you can provide access to the database only for the Web App, and not for the entire internet.

Comment: I actually haven't gotten down to connecting them yet - I ran into a ton of trouble trying to install psycopg2 on my Azure Web App. Though I think I just got successful (hopefully!). I'll keep you posted about how making the connection comes along. I might have a few follow-up questions too, as is the way with these things. Thanks again for replying to the question!